# Does Hostmonster support Django

Tags: django, shared-hosting, hostmonster

I know Hostmonster allows Python. Has anyone successfully run Django on there? Any problems?

Comment: I'm on a shared plan and have access to python 2.6.6, 2.7.3 and 3.2.3. As expected you have little ability to install new packages, but you can use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv to add whatever packages you need (and just point your `fgci` file to your installation). Also, You'll want to use the `--system-site-packages` option when setting up virtualenv

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question, but here is the answer: **yes, Hostmonster does support Django**

There used to be [this Hostmonster KB article](http://helpdesk.hostmonster.com/index.php/kb/article/000531) for details, including instructions on how to set it up, but that link appears to be dead these days, and the only article about Hostmonster article about Django is about [troubleshooting](https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/585). You can find instructions on how to set up Django on Hostmonster [elsewhere](http://www.calebmadrigal.com/django-on-hostmonster/).

Comment: Link's dead
(filling space filling space)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.hostmonsterforum.com/showpost.php?p=20003&postcount=7

I tried the archive the user posted there, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it support Python, you might be able to run Django using a FastCGI setup, as described here: [FastCGI Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/). If it supports mod_python (which I guess it's what you mean), then sure, you can install it using the steps listed here: [ModPython docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/deployment/modpython/)

Answer (score 0):

Hostmonster uses [cPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/) (possible with CentOS), just like other host providers.   If you research into cPanel , you are more likely to get your answer.

Generally, the answer is "no" since out-of-the-box cPanel does not support python 2.5 or mod_wsgi. But it does support Apache2, so it's possible that hostmonster could use mod_wsgi to run sites built with Django.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Github repository for hostmonster and Django it helps me:

[hostmonster-django.markdown](https://gist.github.com/tkaemming/378732)